# How to align the text in a button to the right?

Tags: windows-phone-7, button, text-alignment

This is probably a dumb question but I can't find the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the `HorizontalContentAlignment` attribute. Below is an example:

```
<Button Name="button" Content="Hello World" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"/>
```